# Changing the index format in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I used lucene 4.2 to build the index and I am trying to query the index using 3.6. It throws some exception on index format. I dont want to spend time in rebuilding the index using 3.6.

Is there a workaround for this quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the index with 4.2 in order to be able to read it. The index format has changed, that's why you cannot open a 4.x index with a 3.x lucene.